# JavaScript Promise not resolving event.target.result

Tags: javascript, promise, indexeddb

I need to open transaction, read objectstore data and check if data is not undefined and if data is defined at **indexedDB** use it or if not fetch new data using **network_ip()** function.

But problem is that when i use Promises, the "const r" variable is always undefined with **resolve(e.target.result)**.

**without resolve** the **"r"** variable is defined successfully, but the **result** is empty.

```
const time = new Date().getTime();

async function network_ip(){
    let ipaddr = await fetch('https://example.com/ip.php');
    ipaddr = await ipaddr.text();
    db.transaction(['ip'], 'readwrite').objectStore('ip').put({ip:ipaddr, times:time}, 1);
}

new Promise(function(resolve) {
    db.transaction(['ip'], 'readwrite').objectStore('ip').get(1).onsuccess = function(e){
        const r = resolve(e.target.result); // this line is not working
        if (r !== undefined && r.ip !== undefined && r.times !== undefined) {
            t = r.times;
            i = r.ip;
        }else{
            network_ip();
        }
    }
}).then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Are you sure `e.target` or `e.target.result` exist? If they do, this should work just fine.

Comment: @SebastianSimon yes. I tested it without resolve and e.target.result returs valid result.

Comment: Do `resolve` actually return anything? I always thought it returns `undefined`

Comment: Hold on, I missed this: `resolve` does not return anything. `r` will always be `undefined`, but `result` (in the `then` callback) will have the value of `e.target.result`. Did you mean `const r = e.target.result; resolve(r);`?

Comment: I don't know why you have `if` condition. Will it ever hit?

Comment: The question is bit confusing. `r` will always be undefined. `resolve` is going to return `undefined`. I think you are saying that `result` is going to be undefined, if you are not using `resolve` is that correct?

Comment: @HexaCrop yes. That is

Comment: 'if' is executed if i don't uae resolve but then result of promise is empty

Comment: @redevil are you sure the `onsuccess` is being called? can you also check the `onerror` event? Apart from that I don't see any error in the code

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you want `r` to be assigned the value of `e.target.result` and also have `e.target.result` passed to the `resolve()` function.

What you have doesn't work because `resolve()` doesn't have a return value, so assigning anything to its execution will be undefined. But all you need is to make it into 2 lines:

```js
resolve(e.target.result);
const r = e.target.result;
```

Comment: not working same result